# How to properly set up dev environment using node and npm for Material.io components?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, material-design

I've done the codepens provided by Material.io however when I try to follow the same steps using my own files, I always get an error.

```
> webpack-dev-server --progress

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/bin/config-yargs'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\willy\Desktop\Wireframes-master\Front Page\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\willy\Desktop\Wireframes-master\Front Page\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:54:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\willy\\Desktop\\Wireframes-master\\Front Page\\node_modules\\webpack-dev-server\\bin\\webpack-dev-server.js'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mdc-101-web@0.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --progress`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mdc-101-web@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\willy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-10T15_13_14_365Z-debug.log

C:\Users\willy\Desktop\Wireframes-master\Front Page>webpack-dev-server --progress
'webpack-dev-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I am still new to web development and most of this log is alien to me, I've found similar issues online however their solutions have not fixed my issue.

Versions:

npm: 6.14.4

webpack: 4.42.1

node.js: 12.16.2

UPDATE: It seems that when I first install npm, everything goes just fine, however there a 3 original vulnerabilities. Before I audit fix them, the npm start command works just fine and successfully compiles. When I run the npm audit to see the details of the vulnerabilities, I use the suggested commands to fix them. Once I've done that it no longer works.

Comment: Can you provide a github repo or similar for use to reproduce? In addition, a link to "the codepens provided by Material.io" would be useful.

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-101-web/#0

This was the tutorial I was following, all the way up to 103 when one change of elements did not work. There is a starter code .zip file with each course.

Comment: @DawsonB I really appreciate the feedback, but it seems I was using a too current version of webpack.

Comment: I am getting this issue as well. There is an open bug related to this where I commented that the issue could be fixed by updated documentation, or updating the project to use up to date packages: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-codelabs/issues/144#issuecomment-754754299 In any case, @Griiffiin you said you resolved the issue by downgrading webpack? I think this is a suboptimal solution and would rather use current versions. Regardless can you add an answer that reflects how you fixed it?

Comment: Also, if anyone does have an answer on how to update legacy projects like this to work with current versions, that answer would be much appreciated. Thanks!